# XNA, gameTime and constant fire

Tags: c#, time, xna, controls

I'm trying to define the timespan between shots during constant fire, but got weird behavior with the following attempt:

```
    public void Shoot(GameTime time)
    {
        bullets.Add(new Bullet("bullet", position, angle, content, this, bullets) );
        shotTimer = time.TotalGameTime.Milliseconds;
    }
    public void ShootContinuous(GameTime time)
    {
        if (time.TotalGameTime.Milliseconds - shotTimer > 50)
            this.Shoot(time);
    }
```

The above is called by this:

```
if (newMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    if (oldMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
    {
        player.Shoot(time);
        gui.ProcessClick(newMouseState);
    }
    else
    player.ShootContinuous(time);
}
```

Well, the behaviour is like this: While holding the button, it shoots a volley with a random bullet count between 4-10 and then does nothing until I realese the button, wait a moment and shoot again.

Anyone has an idea what wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `TotalMilliseconds`, not `Milliseconds`, if I understand the code correctly.